# How to move rotation icon to left corner - FabricJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, prototype, fabricjs

When an object(in canvas) is selected, rotation icon is shown at the top of the object. Is there any way to move that icon to the left(or right) corner of the object?

Currently i'm using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210961/how-can-i-change-the-rotation-icon-in-fabricjs) to replace the default rotation icon image of FabricJS, but didn't find anything to move the position of operation icons.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Will you share ur current code in jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by **overriding** default **_drawControl()** method. The [method](http://jsfiddle.net/2XZHp/) you currently following is writing **redundant** code.

```
isVML = function() { return typeof G_vmlCanvasManager !== 'undefined'; };
// overriding _drawControl method
fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Object.prototype, {   
hasRotatingPoint: true,   
cornerSize: 10,
_drawControl: function(control, ctx, methodName, left, top) {
    if (!this.isControlVisible(control)) {
        return;
    }
    var size = this.cornerSize;
    isVML() || this.transparentCorners || ctx.clearRect(left, top, size, size);

    if(control !== 'tl')
        ctx['fillRect'](left, top, size, size);

    var SelectedIconImage = new Image();
    if(control === 'tl') {
        SelectedIconImage.src = 'http://www.navifun.net/files/pins/tiny/Arrow-Rotate-Clockwise.png';
        ctx.drawImage(SelectedIconImage, left, top, size, size);
    }
  }
});
```

Now, for **adding** rotating functionality to icon, **override** following  canvas method:

```
var cursorOffset = {
mt: 0, // n
tr: 1, // ne
mr: 2, // e
br: 3, // se
mb: 4, // s
bl: 5, // sw
ml: 6 // w    
}

fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Canvas.prototype, {  
setCursor: function (value) {
  this.upperCanvasEl.style.cursor = value;
},
_getActionFromCorner: function(target, corner) {
   var action = 'drag';
  if (corner) {
    action = (corner === 'ml' || corner === 'mr')
      ? 'scaleX'
      : (corner === 'mt' || corner === 'mb')
        ? 'scaleY'
        : (corner === 'mtr' || corner === 'tl' )
          ? 'rotate'
          : 'scale';
  }
  return action;
},    
 _setCornerCursor: function(corner, target) {      
 if ((corner === 'mtr' || corner === 'tl') && target.hasRotatingPoint) {
    this.setCursor(this.rotationCursor);
  }
   else if (corner in cursorOffset) {
    this.setCursor(this._getRotatedCornerCursor(corner, target));
  }
  else {
    this.setCursor(this.defaultCursor);
    return false;
  }
 }
});
```

[See the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahbub_rahman/2XZHp/64/)